# How did life for commoners in Okinawa change with the Satsuma invasion?

Tags: japan, social-history, 17th-century

In 1609, the kingdom of Ryukyu which covers what is today known as Okinawa, was [invaded by the Japanese Satsuma clan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_Ryukyu).

How did this affect the everyday life of commoners (Everybody not noble or a priest, for the purpose of this question)?

From the Wikipedia article about the invasion cited above, we learn:

> 14 samurai officials from Satsuma, along with 163 of their staff, examined the kingdom's political structures and economic productivity, and conducted land surveys of all the islands. [...]
>   Though the king [of Ryukyu] retained considerable powers, he was only permitted to operate within a framework of strict guidelines set down by Satsuma, and was required to pay considerable amounts in tribute to Satsuma on a regular basis.

Together with the fact that lack of tributes to the shogunate was at least a pretext for the invasion, this would indicate that the tax burden would be higher under the Satsuma. *Was this so? What other major changes for everyday life came with the invasion?*

Comment: This is an especially complex question given the *very recent* publication of "[**Maritime Ryukyu, 1050-1650**](https://uhpress.hawaii.edu/title/maritime-ryukyu-1050-1650/)" by [Gregory Smits](http://www.personal.psu.edu/gjs4/). His recent paper, April 2019, "Rethinking Early Ryukyuan History" is [available](https://apjjf.org/2019/07/Smits.html) from The Asia Pacific Journal - Japan Focus.